# Defining Clojure -main function in IntelliJ

Tags: clojure, program-entry-point, intellij-idea

I need some very basic advice on how to define a working -main function in IntelliJ along the lines of:

```
(ns clojure.examples.hello
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [greetee]
  (println (str "Hello " greetee "!")))
```

When I create a project, paste the preceding code in a source file, and set the run configuration (with Script path, module, working dev, and "Run script in REPL" selected), I get `:java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: -main in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)"` whenever I run `(-main "Some Greeting")`. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: webdestroya: Thanks for making this actually readable!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that La Clojure's REPL starts in the `user` namespace (as most -- all? -- Clojure REPLs do); you'll have to switch to your project's namespace with `(in-ns 'clojure.examples.hello)` or `(use 'clojure.examples.hello)` to call functions defined there. Better yet, `(require '[clojure.examples.hello :as hello])` and call them as `(hello/-main "IDEA")`.

Comment: Looks like it's a namespace issue and using (in-ns 'clojure.examples.hello) at the REPL command gets me in the proper namespace. IntelliJ chokes on the other commands. Any way to make this  more seamless?

Comment: There is no "more seamless" way. If you want to use the code in a particular namespace you need to either be in that namespace or use that namespace. I usually use the namespace so I more closely emulate what it would be like to use that library in another library.

Comment: Found more seamless way by using Eclipse for Java and Counterclockwise. Dropping IJ and going with E.

Comment: Happy to hear that you found a satisfactory solution. I use Emacs for Clojure programming myself and wouldn't know how to tame La Clojure. Note that both the `use` and the `require` form should work fine if the directory layout of your project matches the structure of your namespace names and the IDE sets up the classpath properly.

Comment: There are more seamless ways. I don't know how CCW or SLIME do it, but VimClojure provides a command to open a repl in the namespace of the current buffer. So no namespace handling required on the user side.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Folks. All were useful and I'm going to try every Clojure IDE out to find one that's just right for me. It'll take a lot of research, quite a few apt-gets, and even an occasional apt-get --purge (in anger), but someday I'll find a Clojure IDE setup all my own!!!